# sharing same string constant in javascript and aspx file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use a `string` constant in javascript ans same `string` for a `label` in index.aspx. Is there any good way to use same javascript constant in `aspx`?

Comment: Do you mean in same page ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a public variable in your (.cs) class file. (make it const if you dont want to change it.) Assign value to it from wherever you want to.

```
public string strName = "Tester";
```

& Use in your .aspx page as :

```
<label> <%: strName %>  </label>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var x = '<%: strName %>';
 </script>
```